# In the AVD manager, what is the relationship between "Device" and "Skin"?

Tags: android, resolution, skin

The "Device" field always contains a resolution and density.

The "Skin" field seems to override the resolution, but not the density.

[image]

Also, the specs enumerated after you create a new AVD only mention the "Skin" if you select something other than "No Skin" or "Skin with dynamic hardware controls".

[image]

Is the word "skin" being using in the same sense as Touchwiz, Blur, Sense, etc.?  Why does that have to do with resolution?

Comment: I think skin is just the physical device representation that will be displayed as your emulator. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing), an android emulator skin represents the devices screen, with its size and density (and it also includes an image of the device).

> The Android SDK includes emulator skins you can use, which replicate the sizes and densities of common screen configurations...